# Windows 10 Desktop Bridge: copy protection

Tags: uwp, windows-10, desktop-application, copy-protection, desktop-bridge

Microsoft offers a tool for packaging standard w32 applications so that they can be published in the Microsoft Store [1]. 
But I could not find any information about copy protection. Are apps distributed through the desktop bridge protected in any way?

Regards,

[1] https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop

Comment: Why should they be? None of the apps distributed through the Windows Store have any sort of copy-protection automatically added, although the store does allow you to easily add licensing (see [Monetization, customer engagement, and Store services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/index) for more information).

Comment: macOS offers such a feature where the application checks on start up with the Apple Store app if the application/its IAPs have been purchased.

Comment: Why would you assume, that the Windows Store didn't offer this service?